# What's the 'canonical table'?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

`What's the 'canonical table?I can't find any description of it.Can anyone provide a example?'

Answer (score 3):

Are you reading [Java Performance Tuning](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javapt/chapter/ch04.html)? I saw those concepts in there.

A canonical object means an object with a single reference pointed to it, with no copies holding the same state possible.

The `activity of replacing multiple copies of an object with just a few objects is often referred to as canonicalizing objects.`

For example Boolean, could have been canocalized, but it were not because new objects can be created with new, thus it's possible to create more than one instance with the same state.

A Canonical Lookup Table is some sort of cache containing references to those canonical object pool.

Comment: Hi Stivlo
Thanks a lot for you help. You're so smart. I'm reading Java Performance Tuning. I'm confused 'Canonical table'.